# How can I get the pinch gesture coordinates from a standard UIScrollView?

Tags: uiscrollview, coordinates, uigesturerecognizer, detect, pinch

I'm needing to implement this method:

```
- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {
```

But I don't have any idea how to get the center coordinates I need. Typically this method handles custom gesture recognizer coordinates, but being that I need a standard UIScrollView's pinch gesture coordinates, I'm stuck...

Ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You have access to the pinchGestureRecognizer of the UIScrollView. Then you can ask for the center coordinate of the pinch gesture with

```
- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view
```

So to get the midpoint between two fingers in your scrollView you can write :

```
CGPoint midpoint = [scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer locationInView:scrollView];
```

Hope this helps,
Vincent